# security intercept url to exclude from universal match pattern

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have intercept url /test/** and now I am trying to create new intercept url as /test/test1 to different access role.

I tried below but not working

```
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="ROLE_TEST" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>

<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/test1" access="ROLE_TEST1" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a `<http>` element for every url you want protected that is going to clutter your configuration, next to the fact that it won't work. Simply add it to the first block. Make sure that the `/test/test1` mapping comes before `/test/**`.

```
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/test1" access="ROLE_TEST1" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="ROLE_TEST" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>
```

See the Spring Security [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-minimal) especially the note.

Comment: And why shouldn't it... That url, judging by the 2 intercept-url elements you have, isn't protected. As mentioned don't create a new `<http>` element just add them into a single element.

Comment: I created one HTTP element inside that I created two intercept-url one with exact url and other with universal pattern. where exact URL should have different access and for universal pattern I have different access. But when I try to access /test/test1 or /test/test2 authentication is not happening..any suggestions?

Comment: The urls you posted don't match the `/test/` based urls so those will not be protected. You will need to add those. `/v1/**` doesn't match `/test/`.

Comment: Sorry Deinum I commented the wrong configuration. I tried the following one <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/test1" access="ROLE_TEST1" requires-channel="https"/>
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="ROLE_TEST" requires-channel="https"/>
        <security:http-basic />
    </security:http>
but still /test/test1 and /test/test2 are not prompting to login

Comment: Make sure you have setup spring security correctly. You need to have a filter in your web.xml and the configuration needs to be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.